# iPhone AVAudioRecorder, AudioQueueServices, how to auto record audio when sound is detected

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

i'm using AVAudioRecorder and AudioQueueServices to record audio from the iphone's mic but I want to auto record the sound once it is detected so theres no need to press on a record button

I've looked at a tutorial about the AVFoundation:
[www.iphoneam.com/blog/index.php?title=using-the-iphone-to-record-audio-a-guide&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1](http://www.iphoneam.com/blog/index.php?title=using-the-iphone-to-record-audio-a-guide&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1)
and also a tutorial that explains how the iphone mic can detect sound levels, i've tried adding the two tutorials together but i cant get the code to work at all

Can't figure out what to do and i'm not sure if i'm taking the wrong approach

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Check out this tutorial: http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/

I got something similar working using the above tutorial. I have one AVAudioRecorder monitoring the mic's volume and another that records the mic's input when a certain threshold is reached.